# Where have I to put an image to use it to create a new Swing ImageIcon object?

Tags: java, swing, embedded-resource, imageicon

I am studying Java Swing library and I have a problem.

In an example program it create an **ImageIcon** object by this line:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("exit.png"));
```

Whe I execute my program I obtain the following error caused by the fact that in the project the **exit.png** is missing:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:205)
    at com.andrea.second.SimpleMenu.initUI(SimpleMenu.java:23)
    at com.andrea.second.SimpleMenu.<init>(SimpleMenu.java:17)
    at com.andrea.second.SimpleMenu$2.run(SimpleMenu.java:53)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

The problem is, using Eclipse, where I have to put this immage?

I tryed to copy and paste it (in my file system, not in Eclipse) an "exit.png" file into the same package folder that contains the class that create it...but it don't work

What have I to do to solve this problem in Eclipse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("exit.png"));
```

You need to put the `exit.png` in the same package as the Class represented by `getClass()`.

With

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/exit.png")); // note leading /
```

You need to put it at the root of your classpath. In Eclipse, that would happen by putting it directly in `src`.

[The `Class#getResource(String)` javadoc states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29)

> Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the
>   given resource name using this algorithm:
>
> If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of
>   the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
>
> Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
>
> modified_package_name/name Where the modified_package_name is the
>   package name of this object with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').

Comment: mmm there is something strange because I use getClass().getResource("exit.png") and I have put the "exit.png" immage into the same directory of the class represented by getClass() but it still don't work...some idea?

Comment: @AndreaNobili Put it in the package of the class that contains this code. Is that what you did? And is the file called exactly `exit.png`?

Comment: Yes, but I have put it by my "computer resource" and not into Eclipse, is it right or have I to insert it by Eclipse? In this eventuality what have I to do to insert an immage into a package using Eclipse? Tnx

Comment: @Andrea I don't know what you mean by computer resource. Just drag and drop the file into Eclipse's package explorer in the right package.